# UISearchDiplayController: show all results without entering text?

Tags: search, tableview, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a `UISearchDisplayController` that is being used to display a long list of options for the user to pick.  I filter the list using the search bar supplied by the controller.

It all works ok, apart from I can't get the results table to display except by entering text into the search bar.  I want to have the table show all the results I have, even when there is no text in the search bar.  At present, when there is no text I just have a dimmed underlying view.

Is this possible please?  Or should I not bother with the `UISearchDisplayController` at all, and just have a searchbar in another tableview that I display, and then just pop it off the stack?

Answer (score 3):

To display search results instantly with empty searchBar upon keyboard appearance, add the following code to ViewController:

```
-(void)searchDisplayControllerDidBeginSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller {
  [controller.searchBar.delegate searchBar:controller.searchBar textDidChange:@" "];
}
```

To keep table showing results when users enter enters some text and then clears searchBox, add:

```
-(void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller didHideSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
  [controller.searchBar.delegate searchBar:controller.searchBar textDidChange:@" "];    
}
```

Don't forget to return YES in *searchDisplayController:shouldReloadTableForSearchString:*

Comment: Perfect! A note to future visitors: ensure your searchBar delegate is set to the UISearchDisplayController if you hoooked things up yourself like I did.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you would want to start by loading all of your content into a single array from which you would display a table view as "normal".

Once this is working, create a second array containing the search results from within

```
- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
```

Then, within the table view's delegate/data source methods, decide which context you are in by checking

```
if (_tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
```